# Setup VM with virtualenv with a shell script

Tags: python, django, bash, postgresql, virtualenv

So I'm trying to streamline my deployment process. I have a VM with Vagrant (Ubuntu Vivid64, virtualenv, django and postgres), but I still have to execute a lot of commands after executing `vagrant up`. I've used this vagrantfile: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-python3-vagrant

This gets executed through the Vagrant provision script:

```
sudo apt-get -qq install git python3-pip > /dev/null 2>&1
sudo pip3 install --quiet virtualenv
sudo pip3 install --quiet virtualenvwrapper
mkdir ~vagrant/.virtualenvs
chown vagrant:vagrant ~vagrant/.virtualenvs
printf "\n\n# Virtualenv settings\n" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
printf "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.4" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
printf "export WORKON_HOME=~vagrant/.virtualenvs\n" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
printf "export PROJECT_HOME=/vagrant\n" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
printf "export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.4\n" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc

printf "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh\n" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
printf "alias python='/usr/bin/python3.4'\n" >> ~vagrant/.bashrc
```

When this is finished, I want to create a new virtualenv and install django in it. Then I want to install postgres and the related packages, create the database for postgres and then install a Python package for the postgres connection. This is the shell script I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt-get update

# Setup virtual environment for Django
mkvirtualenv vms_django
pip3 install django

# Setup Postgres
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev postgresql postgresql-contrib
sudo su Postgres
psql postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE djangodb;
CREATE USER hhhhh WITH PASSWORD 'root';
ALTER ROLE hhhhh SET client_encoding TO 'utf8';
ALTER ROLE hhhhh SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed';
ALTER ROLE hhhhh SET timezone TO 'UTC';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE djangodb TO hhhhh;"
exit

# Setup Postgres Django connection
pip3 install psycopg2

# Migrate DB
python3 manage.py makemigrations
python3 manage.py migrate
python3 manage.py createsuperuser
```

...but that doesn't work. mkvirtualenv and psql commands are not found, and the last three python commands throw importerrors: No module named 'psycopg2'.

Anyone able to lend a hand? Alternative ways to solve my problem are welcome too.

Comment: Your `.bashrc` is likely not being loaded for the script environment. Try loading it manually? Also `sudo su Postgres` does *not* give you an interactive session for the next lines to run in from a script. That's not how it works. It exits immediately. I'm surprised you are seeing the `pip3` and `python3` lines run at all actually (what with that `exit` there).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you know if there's another way to execute the postgres lines?

Comment: You need to run the `psql` command as the command run by `sudo su Postgres` not *after* it.